# Здесь «person» показывает мне ошибку CS7036. Почему это произошло?

Tags: c#

```
static void Main()
{
    person human = new person { age = 4, name = "Lulu" }; //CS7036 Отсутствует аргумент, соответствующий требуемому формальному параметру
}
class person
{
    public int age;
    public string name;
    public person(int age, string name)
    {
        this.age = age; 
        this.name = name; 
    }
}
```

Comment: `new person(4, "Lulu")`

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить конструктор по умолчанию, если вы хотите создавать экземпляр без параметров и указать их в следующем блоке.
Код должен выглядеть так:

```
static void Main()
{
    person human = new person { age = 4, name = "Lulu" };
}
class person
{
    public int age;
    public string name;
    public person(int age, string name)
    {
        this.age = age; 
        this.name = name; 
    }
    public person() {  }
}
```

Comment: Нет, круглые скобки не обязательно ставить. / Вы добавили конструктор по умолчанию - в этом суть.

Comment: Не знал, спасибо за замечание.